# zsh or oh-my-zsh stops autocompleting usernames

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently installed `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` on my ubuntu box, this is my first foray in to a different shell and I've noticed that when I try to do `su - newuser` I can't do tab to autocomplete on the users name anymore.

Is this a problem with zsh itself, or do I need to do some sort of re-indexing to get it to recognize those again?

Comment: Zsh should handle completion for `su` so there must be something wrong with your setup. Do other things work, e.g. options with `su -<tab>` what about for other commands such as `grep`? What about username completion after, e.g. `chown`? I'd also suggest trying plain zsh with `compinit` loaded directly instead of oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Ahh, your suggestion helped me, I don't know why it works this way or if it's normal, but I have to do `su <tab>`, not `su - <tab>`. Weird, but at least it works.